# Fetching data from other tabs

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I want when I write "Yes" in "Count" column of "IP_Details" tab, it will automatically add (+1) to the "Used IP" column of "Dashboard" tab. So when I am using any IP, I don't need to edit in the Dashboard for that entry.

Here I have attached screenshots of this issue.

**1st Tab**
[image: 1st Tab]

**2nd Tab**
[image: 2nd Tab]

Comment: Try adding those example-tables as text into your post. that way more People are inclined to answer

Answer (score 1):

Under `Used IP` you can enter formula: `=COUNTIF(IP_details!D2:D100,"=yes")`, under `Remaining IP` you can enter `Total IP` minus result of given formula.

Apllying OP's remarks below (coments), here's modified answer:

```
=COUNTIF(Public_IP!D2:D100,"=yes") + COUNTIF(Private_IP!D2:D100,"=yes")
```

Comment: Change the name of the sheet in formula. Also, please accept the answer, so it won't need any moderator intervention.

Comment: I need another help. 
If I want to fetch this result from another more tab, like there is 2 tabs named "Public_IP" and "Private_IP" and now I want to get the result of used IPs from both of these tabs to my Dashboard. How will I do this?